# Nsnumber checking digits after floating point

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I am constructing NSNumber object from a float value.`NSNumber *start =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self obj.value]];`

This gives me start value for example

> 14.85

I want to do couple of things here, firstly I want to extract the digits after decimal point. In this case 85, I want to assign 85 to a temp object.
Then i will perform following check on this newly created temp object.

```
if (temp >=30){
start = 14.30;
}
else start== 14.0 ;
```

I have an idea with simple float numbers in C I could achieve this as follows

```
if ((res-(int)res>=30))
        res= (int)res +.30;
        else res = (int)res;
```

Comment: Not really sure why you have a requirement to do arithmetics using Obj-C, when plain C would do. Remember that ObjC is the same C just with added Objective capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example of how you could do it simple:

```
NSNumber *start = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:14.85];
float startFloat = [start floatValue];
int startInt = [start intValue];
int decimalPart =  (startFloat - startInt) * 100 ;

if (decimalPart >= 30){
    NSLog(@"------------- decimalPart >= 30");
    NSLog(@"------------- Do something");

}
else {
    NSLog(@" ------------- decimalPart < 30");
    NSLog(@"------------- Do something");
}
```